# Does vim have a learning mode to help me get used to more advanced operations?

Tags: help-system

I have been using vim for over 5 years and I only ever use basic cursor movements and character/line replacements.  I'm not using multiple windows or buffers or registers or splits. When I want to edit a different file I `:wq`, navigate to the other file, and `vi file`. I often find myself in `VISUAL` mode, not knowing how I got there or what it's for.

I'm sure there are many features that would improve my workflow that I don't even know to look for. Is there a utility or tutorial mode, either within `vim` or without, that helps competent users become aware of the less-obvious features of `vim` and when to use them?

Comment: This question asks about how an intermediate user can master Vim, which is not quite the same as the linked question.

Comment: @200_success The question is much too broad; it talks about buffers, registers, splits, visual mode, etc...

Answer (score 4):

There is `:help tutor` from within Vim. You can also start this from the commandline as:

```
$ vimtutor
```

If you're using MS Windows, you can find it in the start menu under the 'Vim' group.

This is an *interactive* tutorial, where you learn by *doing*, rather than
reading & trying to memorize.

Vim also has some tutorials in the help files, you can view them with [`:help howto`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/howto.txt.html). The [Vim wiki also has a
tutorial](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Tutorial), which may be useful as a
reference.

Also check out [Vim Adventures](http://vim-adventures.com/)

Comment: Whenever a friend wants to learn vim, I always refer them to vim adventures. +1